# Xamarin.Forms Set different Colum Definitions for different platforms (android, ios)

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid

I have this grid:

```
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.07*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This Grid is part of titleview in android and ios. I need to center the icon in the middle column but since ios and android handle the title view differently the icon in the middle does sit slightly more left bound on ios while it sits in the center on android. I would need to set different colum widths for each platform.

Is this doable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to achieve for different Colum Definitions for different platforms (android, ios).

```
    <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  >
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="1.2*"></On>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="2.07*"></On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Epic, that works LIKE A CHARM <3 (just oen side note, my original column was 1.07 in width not 2.07. (might be confusing to some that try to abstract what u did here) Maybe edit it, so people know what exactly happend. thank you :)